# A little help with an if statement

Tags: visualforce

Having a time of setting this if statement specifially where im setting the condition of  callerId.id not null or blank.

```
  if (callerId.id != null){
                    var newLead = "/"+callerId.id;
                    sforce.interaction.screenPop(newLead, true);
                }
```

thanks

Comment: What is callerId?

Comment: got it figured out on  > if (callerId.id.length = 18){

Comment: Hopefully you have a == 18 and not a =18, = is an assignment operator, == is a comparison operator. if you do caller.id.length = 18 your if loop will always be true

Comment: thanks Eric, yes ran into that, ended up using   if(results.length > 0) and it worked like a charm within the logic.